# How to delete comments from a removed table in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, comments, oracle-sqldeveloper

We have a SQL Table that was created with

```
CREATE TABLE EXAM
date DATE NOT NULL;
```

Later we add a comment to the table and another comment to the column 'exam':

```
COMMENT ON TABLE EXAM IS 'Exams of the year';
COMMENT ON COLUMN EXAM.DATE IS 'Date of the exam';
```

The problem is that after remove the table with:

```
DROP TABLE EXAM CASCADE CONSTRAINT;
```

we consult the comments of the column user with:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_COL_COMMENTS;
```

and we found something like that:

BIN$mw7H0FUoSiiAatqV7Hehog==$0      DATE   Date of the exam

and a lot of rows with a table_name like this. Each time I create a table and add a comment to it, and then drop it, I found a new group of rows with similar names (BIN$mw7H0FUoSiiAatqV7Hehog==$0) with the comments of removed tables.

So, I would to know if is possible to remove all this kind of comments.

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you drop a table, it is placed in your recycle bin.  That allows you to undrop the table if you discover that you dropped a table inadvertently.

You can prevent a table from going to the recycle bin by using the `PURGE` clause, i.e.

```
DROP TABLE exam PURGE
```

You can clear everything out of the current user's recycle bin

```
PURGE RECYCLEBIN
```

You can (assuming you have privileges) clear out everything from the recycle bins of every user

```
PURGE DBA_RECYCLEBIN
```

You can disable the recycle bin for the system or for the session

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET recyclebin = OFF scope = BOTH
ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = OFF
```